# Reading Checkbox in Django

Tags: python, django, checkbox, django-forms

This is **NOT** just another Reading Django Checkbox.  I've read through 7 different posts about Checkbox on here along with 4 other pages in Django Documentation.  My situation is a bit different.  I can't read whether a specific checkbox is checked or not.  I just get a value "True" for both checkboxes even when only one checkbox is checked.  If nothing is checked, it worked as expected.  Do I really need to use the MultipleChoiceField?

**Current Output:**

```
- John Doe Location A True   ===> Checked
 - James Smith Location A True    ===> Unchecked
```

Ideally, I would like a list of dictionary that contains

```
data [0] = {'John', 'Doe', 1}
data [1] = {'John', 'Smith', 0}
...
```

where '1' is the flag for overwrite and '0' is to ignore.

**Background:**

1. User submits a form
2. Second form displays the previous information with checkbox next to the names if duplicates are found.  If they're not duplicate, no checkbox will appear.
3. Read in the checkbox, process, and display the final page.

[image: Checkbox Entry]

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms.formsets import BaseFormSet

class NameForm (forms.Form):

    first_name = forms.CharField (max_length = 20, required = False)
    last_name = forms.CharField (max_length = 20, required = False)

class BaseNameFormSet (BaseFormSet):
...

class CheckBox (forms.Form):
    overwrite = forms.BooleanField (required = False)
```

views.py

```
def addname (request):
....

if request.method == 'POST':
    ....

    if formset.is_valid ():
        location = request.POST ['site']
        data = formset.cleaned_data

        # Store data into session to be used in another method
        request.session ['location'] = location
        request.session ['data'] = data


def process (request):

    location = request.session ['location']
    data = request.session ['data']

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CheckBox (request.POST)

        if form.is_valid ():
            overwrite = form.cleaned_data.get ('overwrite')

        # for duplicate in checkboxes:
        #    overwrite = duplicate.get ('overwrite')
        print (overwrite)

        context = {'data': data, 'location': location, 'overwrite': overwrite}
        return render (request, 'nodeform/success.html', context)

    return HttpResponse ('No Overwrite Data.')
```

response.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'nameform/style.css' %}" >
    <title>Submitted Entries</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Submitted Entries:</h1>
    <h4>Location: {{ location }}</h4>
    <form action="process" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    <div id="tablefont">
    <table id="table01">
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th class="center">Overwrite</th>
        </tr>
        {% for info in data %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ info.first_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ info.last_name }}</td>
            <td class="center"><input type="checkbox" name='overwrite-{{ forloop.counter0 }}'></td>  ===> Testing Checkbox
                <!--
                {% if info.overwrite %}
                <td class="center"><input type="checkbox" name='overwrite-{{ forloop.counter0 }}'></td>
                {% else %}
                <td class="center"></td>
                {% endif %}
                -->
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    </div>
    <br>
    {% if errors %}
    <p class="errorlh">Error:
        <ul>
        {% for error in errors %}
            <li>{{ error }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </p>
    {% endif %}
    <br>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Confirm">
    <a href="{% url 'addname' %}">
        <button type="button">Cancel</button></a></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

success.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Successfully Added</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Information captured:</h1>
    <ul>
    {% for info in data %}
        <li>{{ info.first_name }} {{ info.last_name }} {{ location }} {{ overwrite }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <a href="{% url 'addname' %}">Add more names</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The core of your problem is that you appear to be using multiple checkboxes with the same name and same value. When you submit an HTML form, active checkboxes are reported as `name=value` - so you can use checkboxes to collect multiple values that share a name, but it's meaningless to have multiple checkboxes that share both settings. The typical Django solution would be to define one form that includes all fields that you want to track for each row (so first name, last name, location and overwrite) and then use that to build a formset.

Comment: Try giving a different name to each checkbox

Comment: Have you heard about formsets? Maybe it will meet your requirements https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  Let me try to the easy route like Ella pointed out.  I'm thinking of indexing the "name" unless you have a better suggestion.

Yes, I'm aware of formsets.  In fact, this whole form was built on formsets up until the checkbox part.

Comment: @Peter - My first page only collect the first name & last name.  Once that's been process, it will display the second page with the checkboxes for overwrite.  Does that mean I'll have to collect both data twice?

Comment: Generally then you'd pass the already collected names into the formset as initial data, or as part of a queryset to select preexisting records if you're planning to use the formset to edit those records.

Answer (score 0):

All your checkbox inputs have the same attribute `name=overwrite` so, when you check one, it will be the only one submitted in the POST `overwrite=true`.

You should give an unique name to each input. I suggest you to use `{{ forloop.counter0 }}`, it will provide the current iteration of the loop, starting from 0. Basically it is the index of the current "info" in "data".

```html
{% for info in data %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ info.first_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ info.last_name }}</td>
        <td class="center"><input type="checkbox" name='overwrite-{{ forloop.counter0 }}'></td>  ===> Testing Checkbox
            <!--
            {% if info.overwrite %}
            <td class="center"><input type="checkbox" name='overwrite' value="1"></td>
            {% else %}
            <td class="center"></td>
            {% endif %}
            -->
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

This way, you can match the form field in POST to the "info" in the backend.

Comment: You could use the Django form object instead of write the checkbox input yourself to get similar results.

Comment: If this works it would be great without the extra formsets headache.  I did what you suggested but the result is still the same.  My views should collect all the 'POST' data and assigned it to overwrite but it didn't.